# Debuging Windows firewall rules in VS Code with Powershell

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-firewall

I'm working on powershell scripts whose purpose is to add rules to Widnows firewall.
Using VSCode, powershell 5.1 and powershell extension for VSCode.

now there are 2 problems:
First I just want to run debugger to see if the script is executed with no errors, but what happens is that the rule is added to firewall for real.

Is there a way to avoid adding rule to firewall for real, just test if it works, ie. dry-run?

Secondly, I can't debug if VSCode is not run as Admin, obviously since I'm modifiying the firewall.

Now if there is no way to just "dry-run" the script in non elevated mode then how to debug these scripts without running VSCode as Admin?

because otherwise I got "Permission denied" error.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PowerShell: Launch Current File",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is sample script `test.ps1`:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Outbound Port 80" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 80 -Protocol TCP -Action Block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `-WhatIf` switch. The [WhatIf](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/whatif-confirm/) switch will show you what would happen if you ran the command, but it does not run it.

Microsoft has the [New-NetFirewallRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps) information online which also shows the `-WhatIf` switch details.

So try out the below.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Outbound Port 80" -Direction Outbound `
    -LocalPort 80 -Protocol TCP -Action Block -WhatIf
```